# Is Artemis Batman's niece?

Tags: dc, young-justice

In the time stamp of 04:42 and 05:13, Artemis' mom says something that shocks me, she said as she was in jail for her time as **Huntress**, she lost one daughter... but when she said Huntress, Researched to see if i was correct and i believe i am, after looking at [Huntress (DC Comics)](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1CAIXET_enUS931&q=Is%20Huntress%20Batman%27s%20daughter%3F&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj-5ub80snvAhVpTt8KHS_jDacQzmd6BAgREAo&safe=active&ssui=on), I learn that she is Batman's daughter meaning that Artemis is batman's niece, so i'm confused why Artemis had to lie and say that she was Green Arrow's niece?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Please provide the episode you're referencing with the times; by themselves they aren't much use.  Also, please provide the _actual_ page you're looking at and not just the google search.

Comment: @King Sluur  I am not a comics expert, but your question is confusing to me.  You claim that the mother of Artemis is revealed to be Huntress, and that Huntress was Batman's daughteri, and thus that makes Artemis Batman's niece.  But being the daughter of Batman's daughter should make Artemis Batman's granddaughter instead of Batman's niece.

Answer (score 8):

This is revealed as the seasons progress, so it is appropriately contained within a spoiler tag.

In the context of the Young Justice cartoon and it's Earth-16 continuity [Artemis](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Artemis_Crock_(Earth-16)) is

> The daughter of the criminals Paula Nguyen 'Crock' / Huntress and Lawrence Crock / Sportsmaster. She is also the sister of Jade / Cheshire.  Per [DavidW's comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/244998/is-artemis-batmans-niece/244999?noredirect=1#comment672640_244999), Huntress is not Helena Wayne. She has no relation to Bruce Wayne / Batman.

Her unorthodox parentage is the reason she had to say she was Green Arrow's niece. She also stole his color scheme.

[image]

Comment: I think what's important here is this version of Huntress _isn't_ Helena Wayne, it's the first (villain) Huntress, Paula "Crock."  (Paula Brooks in the comics.)

Comment: @DavidW Thanks for that additional clarification.